# Erro publish play store

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, google-play

Tenho uma aplicação na Google PlayStore e começou a gerar esse problema, e não consigo subir minhas alterações no momento:

> Você fez upload de um APK ou Android App Bundle com informações de assinatura inválidas ou ausentes em alguns dos arquivos. Crie um APK ou Android App Bundle assinado válido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já assinei o `.apk` com **jarsigner** e compactei via **zipalign**. Uso **Ionic v3**.

Eu já enviei várias atualizações dessa aplicação, e tenho a assinatura keystore aonde rodo o comando:

```
sudo "jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore MYAPP-release-key.keystore MYAPP.apk MYAPP"
```

e após isso tenho que compactar de acordo com a documentação em:

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Ocorreu que agora está ocasionando está mensagem de erro que está na imagem.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Por favor Daniel, especifique melhor o problema, mas escreva a explicação na pergunta ao invés de escrever a maior parte no título da pergunta, e coloque a mensagem de erro escrita na pergunta também, para facilitar.

Comment: tenho um app na play store e ja enviei varias atualizações, e tenho a assinatura keystore aonde rodo o comando sudo "jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore MYAPP-release-key.keystore MYAPP.apk MYAPP"  e apos isso tenho que compactar de acordo com a documentação em https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html, ocorreu que agora está ocasionando está mensagem de erro que está na imagem